# Strange behavior when comparing int in IF statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am trying to compare two int variables in IF statement. In some cases it works well, but in some cases there's very strange behavior, at least to me. Basically I want to return true when two variables aren't equal.

In pseudocode:

```cpp
if (!someMethodToRetrieveInt() == someStructure.intVariable)
    return true;
return false;
```

While debugging i was checking locals, and i am sure variable returned by method and member of structure were not equal, but code returned false anyway.

Are theese two same?

```cpp
if (!someMethodToRetrieveInt() == someStructure.intVariable)
    return true;
return false;
```

```cpp
if (someMethodToRetrieveInt() != someStructure.intVariable)
    return true;
return false;
```

Comment: Can you show what the method `someMethodToRetrieveInt()` looks like?

Comment: `!someMethodToRetrieveInt()` is going to result in `0` or `1`. `1` when `someMethodToRetrieveInt()` returns `0`, and `0` at all other times. Then it will compare that `0` (or `1`) with `someStructure.intVariable`. So, they are only the same when `intVariable` is constrained to `0` or `1`. Which it *probably* isn't.

Answer (score 3):

No they're not the same because the precedence is wrong `!` has higher precedence than `==`. You need to add some brackets. These two are the same

```
if (!(someMethodToRetrieveInt() == someStructure.intVariable))
    return true;
return false;

if (someMethodToRetrieveInt() != someStructure.intVariable)
    return true;
return false;
```

and both are the same as

```
return someMethodToRetrieveInt() != someStructure.intVariable;
```

which would be my preference.

Beginners often don't realise that

```
if (some_boolean_expression)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

can be written more simply as

```
return some_boolean_expression;
```

Comment: `!(a == b)` is not the same as `a != b` considering operator overloading is a thing.

Comment: @Ayxan True but in this case the comparison seems to be between `ints`.

Comment: When overloading operators, do yourself a favor and ensure `!=` gives same result as `!==`.